# Xcode/ios: How do you get name of image after letting user select one and displaying it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I have code working that lets user select an existing image and have it displaying nicely in UIView on screen.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    self.imageView.image = chosenImage;
    NSLog(@"image is%@",chosenImage);
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

How do I get the name of the file to persist it for future reference?  chosenImage just shows you a bunch of metadata about the file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you see below, you can't get the name of the selected image from `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` using the currently existing API.

Here are UIImagePickerControllerDelegate's available [Editing Information Keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Editing_Information_Keys):

```
NSString *const UIImagePickerControllerMediaType;
NSString *const UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage;
NSString *const UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage;
NSString *const UIImagePickerControllerCropRect;
NSString *const UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL;
NSString *const UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL;
NSString *const UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata;
```

---

However, you may want to make use of [`AssetsLibrary.framework`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ALAssetsLibrary/assetForURL:resultBlock:failureBlock:) to obtain the name of an image managed by Photos application:

```
@import AssetsLibrary;

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [library assetForURL:info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] 
             resultBlock:^(ALAsset *fileAsset) {

      NSLog(@"%@", [[fileAsset defaultRepresentation] filename]);

   } failureBlock:nil];
}
```

Comment: Ok.  Am marking question right.  But if you can't get the original image name, can you recommend a way to give it a new name and save it in app directory?

Comment: @user1904273 I don't think there is a possibility that file name would be somwehat `nil` and, AFAIK there is no way of renaming an existing image in Photos.app using some API.

Comment: The accepted answer is only applicable for selecting image in the gallery. How about for taking photo? The code above is not applicable. Let me know your feedback. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try NSLog(@"%@",info) at the beging of that method and see if the name is in the dictionary.